# In Tensorflow, GPU processing time for the first batch is much loner than any others

Tags: tensorflow

I want to know how each batch be processed in GPU units, so I output the start and end times for each batch。But the processing time for the first batch is much longer than others.
Here is my code to get the processing time for each batch[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Ssn.png)

Here is the processing time for the first four batch in GPU[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig3sa.png)

For comparison, I also output the processing time in CPU[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUWgQ.png)

We can find that although the total time in CPU is longer than GPU, the processing time for first batch is shorter.

Comment: My guess is that usually there's graph setup before running the model, and possibly there's extra setup required for GPU than CPU, thus it's taking longer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But the graph setup is performed in sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()), isn't it?